# how find location within kml file using php

Tags: php

how can i  find the user entered location is within kml file using php. PHP

Comment: Your question looks a bit lazy. Did you try searching through the existing tags [php+kml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php+kml)?

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate over the nodes, compare coordinates and then pick the closest.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear. But I think the following links might be useful for you:

[php-kml](http://code.google.com/p/php-kml/)
and
[KML Generator](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/4070-PHP-Generate-KML-definitions-for-Google-Earth.html)